# json_decode() returns non-readable text

Tags: php, json, encoding

I have such code:

```
 for ($j = 0; $j < mysql_num_rows($subcategoriesData); $j++)
    {
      $subcategoriesStrResult = mysql_fetch_array($subcategoriesData);
      //echo $subcategoriesStrResult['title']."<br>";
      $itemFeatures = array( $subcategoriesStrResult['title'] => $subcategoriesStrResult['path']);
      array_push($arrayDataSubcategoryItems, $itemFeatures);
    };

    array_push($mainArrayForJSON, $item = array(
                                               'parent_id' => $subcategoriesStrResult['parent'],
                                               'level'     => $subcategoriesStrResult['level'],
                                               'items'     => $arrayDataSubcategoryItems
    ));
```

After my `$mainArrayForJSON` is ready I'm trying to check the json-code by the simple echo

```
echo  json_encode($mainArrayForJSON);
```

Meanwhile, to be sure that I get what I need I'm checking the single value of my string by the `echo` too (this string is commented now) - it works OK, I see on Chrome good readable text (in database this text is stored in utf8, of course).

But last call to echo for check the prepared JSON leads me to the next output:

```
[{"parent_id":"8-590","level":"3","items":[{"\u041c\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u043b\u043e\u0442\u043e\u043a BAKS (\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u0430)":"8-590-1404"},{"\u041c\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u043b\u043e\u0442\u043e\u043a INPUK
```

So, I have no idea how to fix it - I tried to hardcode UTF-coding "SET NAMES ..." and called `header()`, and iconv() - last has no sense becouse of I'm sured that my text is in UTF8.

Please, help, thanks.

Comment: This result is absolutely correct for non-ASCII text

Comment: Maybe, it is a page encoding's fault ?

Comment: There is nothing to fix, the output is correct as per JSON encoding rules.

Comment: Anyway I need to obtain readable text. Or as I think when I deserialize the result I will get the correct result ?

Comment: JSON isn't intended to be readable for humans, it's intended to be readable by other JSON parsers. The code you've got there is perfectly valid and readable to a JSON parser.

Comment: @EugeneShmorgun Do you want it to be readable on the web page?

Comment: @user4035 I need to use the values of json-records on the web page in win1251-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output your text on a web page, use javascript. And you'll get your Russian characters. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = "\u041c\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u043b\u043e\u0442\u043e\u043a BAKS (\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u0430";
    alert(a);
</script>
```

Outputs this:

[image]